# Adding geom_text() to ggplot_calendar_heatmap()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've been trying to add overlay text to a calendar.  I have a simple set of 6 groups that provide the colour for each cell.  Now I want to add a running count of days in each group (in character format).

When I take https://github.com/AtherEnergy/ggTimeSeries/blob/master/R/ggplot_calendar_heatmap.R as a source it shows (lines 72-75)

```
#' p1
#' # add new geoms
#' p1 +
#' geom_text(label = '!!!')
```

Now this works with a **fixed** text but I want to vary the text cell-by-cell.
Note that aes(x, y) isn't used in ggplot_calendar_heatmap.

```
StudyDates %>%
ggplot_calendar_heatmap(
'Date',
'NotWorked',
vcGroupingColumnNames = "Year",
dayBorderSize = 0.2,
monthBorderSize = 0.5
)
```

I don't see how to 'transfer the data aes() elements from the above to ...

```
geom_text(StudyDates, 
aes('Date','NotWorked',
label = LabelDay,
),
size=1)
```

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a vector of text the same length as the vector of dates:

```r
library(ggTimeSeries)

set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(date = seq(as.Date('2022-01-01'), as.Date('2022-02-28'),
                            by = 'day'),
                 value = cumsum(rnorm(59)),
                 letter = sample(LETTERS, 59, TRUE))

p1 <- ggplot_calendar_heatmap(df, 'date', 'value') +
      scale_fill_continuous(low = 'green', high = 'red')

p1 + geom_text(label = df$letter)
```

[image]

In your case it seems you have a categorical fill variable, and you want the label to represent the number of consecutive days that a particular category of the fill variable appears. In that case, the following might be closer to what you want:

```r
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(date = seq(as.Date('2022-01-01'), as.Date('2022-02-28'),
                            by = 'day'),
                 Notworked = sample(c('A', 'B', 'C'), 59, TRUE),
                 letter = sample(LETTERS, 59, TRUE))
df$count <- 1
for(i in seq(nrow(df))[-1]) {
  if(df$Notworked[i] == df$Notworked[i - 1]) 
    df$count[i] <- df$count[i - 1] + 1
  else
    df$count[i] <- 1
    
}

p1 <- ggplot_calendar_heatmap(df, 'date', 'Notworked') +
      scale_fill_manual(values = c('steelblue', 'pink', '#F0F0AA'))

p1 + geom_text(label = df$count)
```

[image]

Comment: Well I still have problems...

My data (studyDates2) looks like:

'data.frame': 1096 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Date      : Date, format: "2023-01-01" "2023-01-02" "2023-01-03" "2023-01-04" ...
 $ NotWorked : Factor w/ 7 levels "","Weekend","Weekend/Ferie",..: 3 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 ...
 $ DayCounter: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Year      : num  2023 2023 2023 2023 2023 ...
 $ LabelDay  : chr  "" "" "" "" ...

Comment: Then I have 

ggplot_calendar_heatmap(
StudyDates2,
   'Date',
   'NotWorked',
   vcGroupingColumnNames = "Year",
) +
facet_wrap(~Year, ncol = 1)  +
scale_fill_manual(values = c("white","grey80","grey60", "grey30", "yellow", "orange", "red"),
                  labels = c("", "Weekend", "Weekend/Ferie", "Ferie", "Preavis", "CET", "IDR"),
                  drop = FALSE) +
geom_text(label = StudyDates2$DayCounter)

Comment: But I get
Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (3288): label

Comment: So geom_text(label = StudyDates2$DayCounter)  seems to be outside any aes() statement (even though the aes is invisible with ggplot_calendar_heatmap )

Comment: @SteveG please don't post data or code in the comments. It's better to edit your question to include relevant information such as data and code to make your problem reproducible. You are right about the labels being outside of `aes` - this seems to be how this package works. Do you perhaps have some `NA` values in your data that are causing the lengths to not match up?

Comment: Comments on comments noted. 

I can't see any NAs in StudyDates2$DayCounter but there are zeros and the parameter is an integer

Comment: I have another parameter "DayLabel" where I have changed DayCounter to character and replaced zeros by an empty space "".


geom_text(label = StudyDates2$DayLabel)  doesn't work either!